# Waiting on multiple background threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, thread-safety, monitoring

I want know when all thread has been finished in a multithread program

without something like pooling

```
while(!allThreadFinished){
thread.sleep(100);
}
```

The solution should be used Monitor but i can't how can i approve that it's correct.
since the "SomeMethod" in the following code using network, it consume times.

```
public object SomeMethod(string input);
public object[] MultiThreadMethod(string[] inputs) {
            var result = new object[inputs.Count()];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in inputs) {
                BackgroundWorker work = new BackgroundWorker();
                work.DoWork += (sender, doWorkEventArgs) => { doWorkEventArgs.Result = SomeMethod(item); };
                work.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, runWorkerCompletedEventArgs) => { 
                    result[i] = runWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result; 
                };
                i++;
                work.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //**wait while all thread has been completed**
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Since you're using `BackgroundWorker` it must mean you're in a GUI environment, in which case you shouldn't be blocking until they all finish, you should continue on and simply run some code once they are all done.  Either that, or you aren't in a UI environment (or already are in a background thread) in which case you shouldn't be using BackgroundWorker here.

Comment: you mean it's better to use Thread?

Comment: Well, it depends.  Are you in a GUI environment?  Is this method running from the UI thread?  If so, you shouldn't be blocking at all, you should be creating the background tasks and then simply executing some code when they are all done.  If you're not in a UI thread and you really do need to block, then you should probably be using `Task`s rather than BackgroundWorkers (or threads).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx

// Sequential version

```
foreach (var item in sourceCollection)
    Process(item);
```

// Parallel equivalent

```
Parallel.ForEach(sourceCollection, item => Process(item));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the TPL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx.

```
 List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

 Task t1 = new Task(() =>
 {
    // Do something here...

 });
 t1.Start();
 tasks.Add(t1);

 Task t2 = new Task(() =>
 {
    // Do something here...

 });
 t2.Start();
 tasks.Add(t2);

 Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: You'd want `Task<object>` here, not `Task` as they each return a result.

Comment: Well, yes, but where `TResult` is of type `object`.  The method isn't generic (although doing that might not be a terrible idea).  If you choose to have the tasks not return anything then you'll need to have them all add the items to a collection in the body of the task and ensure that it is done so without creating race conditions.

Comment: Best Answer... I used Data Parallelism for this question.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use TPL to do the same, you will avoid using Thread.Sleep(), and it will be much clearer. Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610.aspx

Your example with TPL would look like this (untested code):

```
    private ConcurrentBag<object> _results;
    public object[] MultiThreadMethod(string[] inputs)
    {
        _results = new ConcurrentBag<object>();
        var tasks = new Task[inputs.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(inputs[i]));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        return _results.ToArray();
    }

    private void DoWork(string item)
    {
        _results.Add(SomeMethod(item));
    }
```

EDIT: Without ConcurrentBag:

```
public object[] MultiThreadMethod(string[] inputs)
    {
        var tasks = new Task<object>[inputs.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = Task<object>.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(inputs[i]));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
        return tasks.Select(task => task.Result).ToArray();
    }

    private object DoWork(string item)
    {
        return SomeMethod(item);
    }
```

Comment: You don't actually use (or need) your concurrentbag.  WaitAll returns an array of the results of each task, which is exactly what he needs.

Comment: You don't need to select the results from the `tasks` array.  As I said, `WaitAll` returns the results as an array already, just return the results of `WaitAll`.

Comment: Are you sure? In fwk 4 Task.WaitAll(tasks); is void or returns bool. Maybe you mean another way..

Comment: Ah, I'm thinking `WhenAll`.  You could `return Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result;`.

Comment: Ok! Is another valid approach. Good to know! Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Hook the `RunWorkerCompleted` event on the `BackgroundWorker`.  It will fire when the work is done.

A complete example of how to use the BackgroundWorker properly can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Comment: I use RunWorkerCompleted in the Code.
but i want know when all of them are finished.